# Is this tail behavior in Grouping Commands specified by POSIX?

Tags: pipe, tail, posix

Using `tail` combined with other standard tools in [Grouping Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) can make some powerful constructions. For example, to get the first and last line of a file:

```
$ seq 10 > file
$ { head -n1; tail -n1; } <file
1
10
```

When feeding file contents from a pipe to group commands, `tail` fails to produce output, because a pipe is *un-*[lseek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html)*able*:

```
$ seq 10 | { head -n1; tail -n1; }
1
```

Now, when the content is big enough, `tail` works:

```
$ seq 10000 | { head -n1; tail -n1; }
1
10000
```

That's because after the first `lseek` failure, `tail` know it's not a *lseekable* file descriptor and because the contents of the pipe haven't been read all yet, it starts to read the content till the end.

As the user point of view, I expect that the behavior should be consistent regardless of input content size. I've looked through POSIX `tail`, `lseek` documentation and didn't find out any description.

Is this behavior specified by POSIX? If not, how can I make the result to be always consistent?

---

I have tested with GNU tail and FreeBSD tail, both have the same behavior.

Comment: it might be worth pointing out that splitting input like that with `tail` probably isn't particularly useful, and might actually make for more work under the hood. as stéphane mentions, it requires extra input validation for a `tail` than can simply seek through to the end of input because it has to compare that input offset to one it might `lseek()` to, and the outcome is no different than `head -n1 file; tail -n1 file`. i find that stuff more useful when slicing input off of the top: `while IFS= read -r v; do { printf %s\\n "$v"; head; } >&"$((1+(x=!x)))"; done <in >out1 2>out2`

Comment: actually, i guess when you group `tail` at the least it shouldn't print overlap, so there's that, of course. my apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the problem is not with `tail` but with `head` here which reads from the pipe more than the first line it is meant to output (so there's nothing left for `tail` to read).

And yes, it's POSIX conformant.

`head` is required to leave the cursor within stdin just after the last line it has output when the  input is seekable, but not otherwise.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html:

> When a standard utility reads a seekable input file and terminates without an error before it reaches end-of-file, the utility shall ensure that
>              the file offset in the open file description is properly positioned just past the last byte processed by the utility. For files that are not
>              seekable, the state of the file offset in the open file description for that file is unspecified.

For `head` to be able to do that for a non-seekable file would mean it would have to read one byte at a time which would be terribly inefficient¹. That's what the `read` or `line` utility do or GNU `sed` with the `-u` option.

So you can replace `head -n 20` with `gsed -u 20q` if you want that behaviour.

Though here, you'd rather want:

```
sed -e 1b -e '$b' -e d
```

instead. Here, only one tool invocation, so no problem with an internal buffer that can't be shared between two tool invocations. Note however that for large files, it's going to be less efficient as `sed` reads the whole file, while for seekable files `tail` would skip most of it by *seeking* near the end of the file.

See the related discussion about buffering at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716).

<strike>Note that `tail` must output the tail of the stream on stdin. While, as an optimisation and for seekable files, implementations may seek to the end of the file to get the trailing data from there, it is not allowed to seek back to a point that would be before the initial position at the time `tail` was invoked (Busybox `tail` used to have that bug).</strike>

So for instance in:

```
{ cat; tail -n 1; } < file
```

Even though `tail` could seek back to the last line of `file`, it does not. Its stdin is an empty stream as `cat` left the cursor at the end of the file; it's not allowed to reclaim data from that stream by seeking further backward in the file.

<sup>(Text above crossed out pending [clarification by the Open Group](https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02417.html) and considering that it's not done correctly by several implementations)</sup>

---

<sup>¹ The `head` builtin of `ksh93` (enabled if you put `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of `$PATH`), for sockets (a type of non-seekable files) instead *peeks* at the input (using `recvfrom(..., MSG_PEEK)`) prior to actually *reading* it to see how much it needs to read to make sure it doesn't read too much. And falls back to reading one byte at a  time for other types of files. That is slightly more efficient and  I believe is the main reason why it implements its pipes with `socketpair()`s instead of `pipe()`. Note that it's not completely  fool proof as there's a race condition that could be triggered if another process read from the socket in between the *peek* and the *read*.</sup>

Comment: I want to know about the `tail` behavior. After the first failed `lseek`, it started to read the content. While in `seq 10000 | tail -n1`, it did not even try to perform any `lseek`. Did POSIX define `tail` behavior if `lseek` fail?

Comment: @cuonglm, if my reading of Stephane's answer is correct, with `seq 10 | { head -n1; tail -n1; }`, `tail` is left with nothing to read because `head` has greedily slurped up the input. In any case it would not make sense for `tail` to attempt an `lseek` on non-seekable file

Comment: @cuonglm, it only lseeks for seekable files (which it probably determines with a `fstat(0)`). See also my edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for thorough answer ( as always :) ). The last wondered thing in my mind, that when the first `lseek` try failed, do POSIX allow `tail` to discard `lseek` try and changing its behavior to read the file till the end?

Comment: The `lseek()` is an implementation choice for optimisation, POSIX specifies the behaviour, which is to get the tail of input not the details of how it should be done. In anycase, I don't see GNU `tail` attempting let alone failing `lseek` when the input is a pipe.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas; In `strace -fe lseek sh -c 'seq 10 | { head -n1; tail -n1; }`, I saw `tail` do only one `lseek`. And as my comment above, in `seq 10000 | tail -n1`, `tail` even didn't do any `lseek`.

Comment: @cuonglm, most likely what you're seeing is `head` attempting an `lseek()` (to bring the cursor at the end of the first line), not `tail`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ah, my bad. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `tac` does that same buggy `tail` thing, though its not specified one way or the other, of course. `{ cat; tac; } < file`

Comment: great quote for the `head` behavior. Is there a similar reference for *"it [tail] is not allowed to seek back to a point that would be before the initial position at the time tail was invoked"*?

Comment: I ask because [FreeBSD's `tail` utility](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/b75e4698e930e0e5f87f806092cf5345049b0d08/usr.bin/tail/forward.c#L96) breaks this behavior (it can mmap).

Comment: @jfs, hmmm, you're right, there doesn't seem to be anything in POSIX requiring that (even allowing that by some reading) and not many implementations do it. Not even busybox. So either they've reverted the change or it's my memory playing tricks on me (the latter more likely). I'll raise the question to the Austin Group.

Comment: @jfs, see edit and discussion at https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg02417.html

Comment: Why 'sed -e 1b -e '$b' -e d' and not the much simpler 'sed -n '1p;$p'

Comment: Also, on a medium size file `seq 100000000>file`, the sed command takes more than 10 seconds while a `head -n1 file; tail -n1 file` takes just 0.011 seconds.

Comment: @isaac, `sed -n '1p;$d'` would print the content of a one-line file twice. Good point about your second comment. Thanks. See edit.

Comment: Ah, interesting, thanks. Maybe `sed -n '1{p;b};$p'` then?.

Comment: @isaac, that would work with GNU `sed`, but portably, you'd need: `sed -ne '1{p;b' -e '}' -e '$p'`. `b};$p` branches to the `"};$p"` label in `sed` implementations based on the original one. If you wanted a shorter one, you could do `sed -e 1b -e '$!d'` but I find it less legible than `sed -e 1b -e '$b' -e d`.